# How to restore the tab position after back from activity

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, back

I am using a Listview in Tab Fragment (it has 3 Tabs), when clicking on the listview,  start a webviewer and it can back by back button.

After the list click , it call a new activity (Intent), then the Tab will override and a Back button show.

The problem that how can I keep the Tab location and restore it after back from the webview activity.

**API:21 in Android Studio

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define an int to keep the track of the current tab in your class:

```
public static SharedPreferences mSetupSharedPreferences;
public static final String CURRENT_TAB = "currentTab";
private static final in mCurrentTab;
```

Use shared preferences to save this mCurrentTab permanently, place this code in OnCreate ():

```
mSetupSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SETUP_PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// If it does not contain the CURRENT_TAB then create one
    if (! mSetupSharedPreferences.contains(CURRENT_TAB)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor setup_editor = mSetupSharedPreferences.edit();
        setup_editor.putInt(CURRENT_TAB, 1); // 1 means the current tab number is 1
        setup_editor.apply();
    }
```

Now save the current tab whenever user switches the tab:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSetupSharedPreferences.edit();
 editor.putInt(CURRENT_TAB, current_tab);
```

And when the user presses back button then read the current  tab and set the view:

```
int currentTab = mSetupSharedPreferences.getInt(CURRENT_TAB, 0)
switch (currentTab) {
  case  1: // Switch tab view here to 1
  break;
  case  2: // Switch tab view here to 2
  break;
  case  3: // Switch tab view here to 3
  break;
}
```